# stored procedure sql case or if else displaying all records using single query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

ok i have 
**ID    TITLE    CONTENT   DATEPUBLISH    DATEEXPIRED     PUBLISH** as my content table

i want to display all records in the table based upon these conditions using one query.

i have datepublish as a textbox ,dateexpired as a textbox and publish as a checkbox.

1) if i enter datepublish the content will be publish without expiry.

2) if i enter datexpire the content will start publishing straight away and will expire when it reaches the expiry date

3) if i enter both dates then the content will start on the datepublish and will expire when dateexpired

the other thing is that

4) if i checked publish then it will bypass the dates.

**how can i display all records using a single query?**.( i am able to do it with cursor)

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you've done these as seperate queries, if you've tried at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ((@datePublish IS NULL OR Table.datePublish > @datePublish)
    AND (@dateExpired IS NULL OR Table.dateExpired < @dateExpired))
    OR @published = 1
```

If either of your date values is empty, then you pass NULL to your stored procedure for that parameter (thus that parameter won't restrict the result set), and @published = 1 if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: well the thing is that i have stored procedure GetAllPublishContent which will not take any parameters just return all the rows from table based upon the criteria i mentioned

Comment: How is the stored proc using the criteria if you aren't passing them in as parameters?

Comment: i am sorry i have written the things as i took them. the thing is that there is no criteria just i have all the records in the database in the table. i just want to display all the records in the datalist based upon scenario above.

Comment: If you can't modify the stored procedure, is it possible for you to perform filtering on the data once you have retrieved it into your application? What language/platform is your app written in? For example, if you used VB/C#.Net, you could use LINQ on the DataSet returned by your stored procedure.

Comment: @mazhar kaunain baig. I think a better question is,  If you can't change the query why are asking how it should be changed